# Create a column with shots conceded in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(game_id = c(303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 
303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L, 303377L), minute = c(11L, 
13L, 21L, 25L, 32L, 38L, 47L, 58L, 65L, 69L, 71L, 73L, 73L, 76L, 
79L, 89L), home_team = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
), team_name = c("Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Getafe", "Getafe", 
"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Getafe", 
"Barcelona", "Getafe", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
"Getafe", "Barcelona"), type_name = c("shot", "shot", "shot", 
"shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", 
"shot", "shot", "shot", "shot", "shot")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), groups = structure(list(game_id = 303377L, .rows = structure(list(
    1:16), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I created a column that counts the number of shots provided per team:

```
library(plyr)
df1 <- ddply(df1, .(game_id, team_name), transform, shots = cumsum(type_name == "shot"))
df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(game_id, minute)), ]

# Output
   game_id minute home_team team_name type_name shots
1   303377     11      TRUE Barcelona      shot     1
2   303377     13      TRUE Barcelona      shot     2
12  303377     21     FALSE    Getafe      shot     1
13  303377     25     FALSE    Getafe      shot     2
3   303377     32      TRUE Barcelona      shot     3
4   303377     38      TRUE Barcelona      shot     4
5   303377     47      TRUE Barcelona      shot     5
6   303377     58      TRUE Barcelona      shot     6
14  303377     65     FALSE    Getafe      shot     3
7   303377     69      TRUE Barcelona      shot     7
15  303377     71     FALSE    Getafe      shot     4
8   303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     8
9   303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     9
10  303377     76      TRUE Barcelona      shot    10
16  303377     79     FALSE    Getafe      shot     5
11  303377     89      TRUE Barcelona      shot    11
```

Now, what I would like to do as well, is creating another column that indicates the shots conceded per team. That is, if for example Barcelona shoots 2 times, Getafe should eventually have the value 2 for shots_conceded. but I wouldn't really know how to do this.

See the output as example:

```
   game_id minute home_team team_name type_name shots shots_conceded
1   303377     11      TRUE Barcelona      shot     1     0
2   303377     13      TRUE Barcelona      shot     2     0
12  303377     21     FALSE    Getafe      shot     1     2
13  303377     25     FALSE    Getafe      shot     2     2
3   303377     32      TRUE Barcelona      shot     3     2
4   303377     38      TRUE Barcelona      shot     4     2
5   303377     47      TRUE Barcelona      shot     5     2
6   303377     58      TRUE Barcelona      shot     6     2
14  303377     65     FALSE    Getafe      shot     3     6
7   303377     69      TRUE Barcelona      shot     7     3
15  303377     71     FALSE    Getafe      shot     4     7
8   303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     8     4
9   303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     9     4
10  303377     76      TRUE Barcelona      shot    10     4
16  303377     79     FALSE    Getafe      shot     5     10
11  303377     89      TRUE Barcelona      shot    11     5
```

Comment: `ddply` is not in `dplyr`, it looks like you're loading `plyr` instead.

Comment: That was a misspell, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get shots conceded by subtracting `shots` from the cumulative number of shots taken:

```
df1 <- ddply(df1, game_id, transform, shots_conceded = cumsum(type_name == "shot") - shots)

   game_id minute home_team team_name type_name shots shots_conceded
1   303377     11      TRUE Barcelona      shot     1              0
2   303377     13      TRUE Barcelona      shot     2              0
3   303377     21     FALSE    Getafe      shot     1              2
4   303377     25     FALSE    Getafe      shot     2              2
5   303377     32      TRUE Barcelona      shot     3              2
6   303377     38      TRUE Barcelona      shot     4              2
7   303377     47      TRUE Barcelona      shot     5              2
8   303377     58      TRUE Barcelona      shot     6              2
9   303377     65     FALSE    Getafe      shot     3              6
10  303377     69      TRUE Barcelona      shot     7              3
11  303377     71     FALSE    Getafe      shot     4              7
12  303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     8              4
13  303377     73      TRUE Barcelona      shot     9              4
14  303377     76      TRUE Barcelona      shot    10              4
15  303377     79     FALSE    Getafe      shot     5             10
16  303377     89      TRUE Barcelona      shot    11              5
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df1)[, shots := cumsum(type_name == "shot"), by = .(game_id, team_name)]
df1[, shots_conceded := cumsum(type_name == "shot") - shots, by = game_id]
```

Comment: Thanks! The datatable provides a better option for the rest of my dataset :)